# XSLT Add Element Recursively

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am brand new to XSLT and trying to transform an incoming file to then be processed by another program. The goal is to try and add blank lines to an existing XML file to mimic the page length for the other program to process correctly. I need to count the `<line>` elements between each `<page>` element and if that total is less than 75, add the remaining lines as blank. What is the best way to recursively add a blank line in XSLT? So far my incoming XML looks like this:

```
<page>
    <line>Some text</line>
    <line>Some text</line>
    <line>Some text</line>
    etc...
</page>
```

I have been looking at examples that use nodes to group things together like this (setting the group size variable):

```
<xsl:call-template name="file">
     <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select=".|following-sibling::*[not(position() > $pGroupSize - 1)]"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

I have also been finding results that talk about segmented recursion like the example below:

```
<xsl:template name="priceSumSegmented">
  <xsl:param name="productList"/>
  <xsl:param name="segmentLength" select="5"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="count($productList) > 0">
      <xsl:variable name="recursive_result1">
        <xsl:call-template name="priceSum">
          <xsl:with-param name="productList"
            select="$productList[position() <= $segmentLength]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="recursive_result2">
        <xsl:call-template name="priceSumSegmented">
          <xsl:with-param name="productList"
            select="$productList[position() > $segmentLength]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$recursive_result1 + $recursive_result2"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="0"/></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>
```

Any help on the best way to approach this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you restrict yourself to XSLT 1? In XSLT 2 and later you have the XPath 2 `to` expression to construct a sequence of e.g. `1 to (75 - count(line))` to do it without recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Even in XSLT 1.0, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="page">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="line"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-lines">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="75 - count(line)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-lines">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:if test="$n > 0">
        <line/>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-lines">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked out perfectly. Definitely was thinking this would be more complicated. Appreciate the help.